# Как вынести переменную с AsyncTask в основной поток? (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

через сокет получаю информацию с сервера, присваиваю его в переменную, теперь нужно этот полученные текст вставить в TextView, подскажите, как это сделать? Вот я написал, полученное значение присваивается в переменную, но текст в TextView не меняется. Как правильно сделать?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText el;
private TextView text;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    el = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

  }

public void send_data (View v) {
    String message = el.getText().toString();
    BackgroundTask bl = new BackgroundTask();
    bl.execute(message);
  }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... voids) {
    try {
        String message = voids[0];
        Socket s = new Socket("10.195.42.158", 8000);
        InputStreamReader listen = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(listen);
        String msg = buff.readLine();
        text.setText(msg.getText());


    }catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
}
```

Здесь в переменную типа String msg присваивается полученное сообщение от сервера, хочется теперь изменить текст TextView на текст переменной msg

Answer (score 1):

Для обновления графических компонентов, и передачи информации в `UI`-поток вы должны использовать метод `AsyncTask`-a `onPostExecute()`.
Пример использования `AsyncTask` с [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) в котором отображено использование данного метода:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Схема которая отображает как выполняется `AsyncTask`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если мне не для UI нужно, а просто вынести переменную?

Comment: вынеси переменную msg в поле AsyncTask-a и и выполни в методе onPostExecute() text.setText(msg).

Comment: А можно метод onPostExecute добавить внутрь цикла?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда, нет - его вообще не стоит вызывать напрямую. В цикле Вы можете использовать `publishProgress(msg)` - это приведёт к вызову `onProgressUpdate(...)` в UI-потоке и параметром придёт то, что Вы передали. Здесь можно и вывести в `TextView`

Comment: То есть, внутри AsyncTask я могу добавить цикл и в процессе итераций обращаться к методу onProgressUpdate (который будет вне цикла) передавая через publishProgress промежуточные данные?

Comment: @UjinUkr можно посоветовать, почему вы ему не написали использовать AsyncTask, ведь он устарел?

Comment: @danilshik, ну хорошо, давайте загрузим человека, который изучает азы, непростыми лоадерами, хендлерами. Человек задал конкретный вопрос связаный с AsyncTask.